# get_absolute_url doesn't load the page

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-urls

So I am trying to code a blog and have a special page for every article and I have the `blog.html` (main page of the blog) that has the "Read more" button.

```
<a class = "Read" href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">Read more...</a>
```

And I have the another file `post.html` which is the base template for every article page. The Post model has the slug field and the urls.py is like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.front, name='front'),
    url(r'^blog/', views.blog, name='blog'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', views.page, name='post')
]
```

And the page view is like this:

```
def page(request, slug):
    return render_to_response('home/post.html', {
        'post': get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    })
```

The problem is when I press read more nothing happens but I look at the terminal window and the server takes it as a request and return 200 which means success but the page doesn't load.

Edit: 
The Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(default=uuid.uuid1, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='w')
    description = models.TextField(default='', max_length=300)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

     def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title

     def edit_text(self, text):
         self.text = text

     class Meta:
          get_latest_by = 'creation_date
```

Comment: What does the `get_absolute_url` method on Post look like?

Comment: Looking at the code, you haven't defined any such method, so it can't possibly work. If you look at the generated HTML you will undoubtedly see that the href is blank. That's why clicking on the link just takes you back to the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the problem.
Please try to close the url patterns by `$`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.front, name='front'),
    url(r'^blog/$', views.blog, name='blog'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^blog/((?P<slug>.*)/$', views.page, name='post')
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you defined `get_absolute_url` for Post Model?

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
   #fields

   def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('post', args=[self.slug])
```

Comment: It goes to the link but it doesn't load the template.

Comment: Please use `url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>.*)/$', views.page, name='post')` and let me know if it works. Would you share your urls.py? Maybe it is caught by other view.